# How to write an IF..ELSE IF or CASE statement in Azure Data Factaroy

Tags: if-statement, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

This is my doubt. In my **Pipeline** I've got a parameter provided by the final user. I need to check it to return the right value. So far, I have only seen this structure ***IF(condition, true, false)***. But in my scenario this could be complicated to understand/maintain because I would get multiple nested conditions ***IF(condition, true, IF(Condition, true, ...))***

So, I'm wondering if it is possible to get an easier way to write this, something similar to and if-else or case statement. Something like this:

```
CASE @parameter 
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE '4'
END
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-switch-activity) activity in Azure Data Factory (ADF)?

Comment: It is not part of the functions or expressions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#if . I can not use it in a pipeline, probably in a data flow.

Comment: You can use Switch in the main pipeline.  Please read through the link again and try it out.

Comment: You are right. I did not understand the solution at the beginning but this can work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [wBob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527504/wbob) for providing the solution, posting it as an answer for the reference of other community members.

You could use `Switch Activity` in `Data Flow` in Azure Data Factory : The Switch activity provides the same functionality that a switch statement provides in programming languages. It evaluates a set of activities corresponding to a case that matches the condition evaluation.